# UK Tier 2 visa - Naric certificate didn't scanned by VFS but they signed checklist

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, immigration, uk-visa

I am a nurse applying for a UK Tier 2 visa and I have all of the necessary supporting documents. I chose to upload the documents myself through the VFS portal, but due to the large file size, I decided to scan the Naric certificate at their office. During the process, they did not ask for the Naric certificate, but instead signed the checklist to state that all documents had been received. I asked them if I needed to submit anything else and they said no, after completing the Biometric assessment.

Now I am worried about my visa process. If they require any additional documents, will they email me?

Answer (score 1):

If UKVI requires any additional documents regarding your application they would definitely email you.